# Tabulator - Sorting groups by group calcResults

Tags: tabulator

Is it possible to order results of grouped items by the calculation results for each group?  It seems that when I set the initialSort (or when I don't)it sorts by the order of the items within each group, rather than by the total calculation of each group.

For example, if I have data that looks something like this:

```
[
{id:1, company:"company 1", quantity:"10"}, 
{id:2, company:"company 1", quantity:"10"}, 
{id:3, company:"company 1", quantity:"10"}, 
{id:4, company:"company 2", quantity:"20"}, 
{id:5, company:"company 2", quantity:"1"}, 
{id:6, company:"company 2", quantity:"1"}, 
{id:7, company:"company 3", quantity:"9"}, 
{id:8, company:"company 3", quantity:"9"}, 
{id:9, company:"company 3", quantity:"9"}, 
]
```

I would end up with groups ordered:

```
Company 2: 22 // Highest qty 20
company 1: 30 // Highest qty 10
company 3: 27 // Highest qty 9
```

What I am trying to get is:

```
company 1: 30 
company 3: 27
Company 2: 22
```

I can see the calculation results, but I'm not sure how to resort the groups, assuming it's possible. If anyone can point me in the right direction I will be quite grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Rows can only be sorted according to a field stored in the row data.

Rows are sorted individually and then grouped, with groups appearing in the order of the sorted data.

In order to sort your table in this way, you would need to analyse your row data first before ingesting it into the table, and then set a field on each row with the desired order for the group that contains it.

The other option is to manually specify the groups you want using the `groupValues` option, with this approach you specify the exact groups you want and the order they should appear:

```js
groupValues:[["male", "female", "smizmar"]]
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  Now I know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Oli for pointing me in the direction of 'groupValues'.  I ended up writing a function that uses the calcResults to get the sort order I want and then push them into groupValues to get the ordering I'm looking for.

```
const sortByGroupCalc = ( thisTable, thisSortField, thisSortDirection ) => {

  // Temp arrays
  let tempCalcArray = [];
  let tempSortArray = [];

  // Get calculation results
  const calcResults = thisTable.getCalcResults();

  // Populate Array with key:value pairs from the caculation results
  for( const [key, value] of Object.entries(calcResults)) {
    tempCalcArray.push([key, value.top[thisSortField]])
  };

  // Sort the object by value and direction and then create an array of the keys
  tempCalcArray
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      if( thisSortDirection === 'asc' ) {
        return a[1] - b[1];
      } else {
        return b[1] - a[1];
      }})
    .map( 
      x => tempSortArray.push(x[0]) 
    );
  
  // Set group order according to sort order
  thisTable.setGroupValues([tempSortArray]);
}
```

I'm calling it in the dataSorted function. It's not perfect for all occasions, I imagine.  But it seems to do what I need.

Thanks again.